# Travelling Salesman Problem Nearest neighbor heuristic

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

One criticism of the nearest-neighbor TSP heuristic is that the last edge added (from the last city back to the starting city) can be very long. How much eﬀect can that last edge have on the ratio NN/OPT ?